# Find the most common value across multiple variables in SAS

Tags: sas

I would like to:

1. Count the number of times each value appears across multiple variables (year1 to Year5)
2. find the most common value across multiple variables (year 1 to Year 5).

Note: there are cells with no values.

I have the following data:

| ID | Year1 | Year2 | Year3 | Year4 | Year5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 19 | 19 | 19 | 19 | 19 |
| 2 | 5 | 5 | 9 |  |  |
| 3 | 12 | 45 | 11 | 12 | 12 |
| 4 | 14 | 15 | 10 | 14 |  |
| 5 | 20 | 20 | 19 | 19 | 28 |

I need a table that looks like this:

| ID | Count_Year1 | Count_Year2 | Count_Year3 | Count_Year4 | Count_Year5 | Most common Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 19 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 |  |  | 5 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 12 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |  | 14 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | tie |

In the table above, variables with the name "Count_year(n)" shows the count of the value across the "year" variables in the initial table, and the last variable "Most common Value" shows the actual value that appears the most times.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume year1-years5 are numeric variables. This is the first version came to my mind, without any SAS tricks.

```
data have;
  input id$ year1-year5;
  cards;
1 19 19 19 19 19
2  5  5  9  .  .
3 12 45 11 12 12
4 14 15 10 14  .
5 20 20 19 19 28
;
run;

data want;
  set have;

  array _year_ year1-year5;
  array _cyear_ count_year1-count_year5;
  do i=1 to dim(_year_);
    if _year_[i]^=. then do j=1 to dim(_year_);
      _cyear_[i]=sum(_cyear_[i],_year_[i]=_year_[j]);
    end;
  end;

  max_count=max(of _cyear_[*]);
  do i=1 to dim(_year_);
    if _cyear_[i]=max_count then do;
      if common_value=. then common_value=_year_[i];
      else if _year_[i]^=common_value then common_value=.T;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

The special missing value ".T" means there is a tie in raw data.

Comment: I find a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62342714/identify-most-frequent-number-across-variables-and-largest-number-of-the-most-fr/62390710, but it doen't ask for output tie flag.

Answer (score 0):

In order to compute the `MODE` of an array you will need to compute a frequency count table and obtain the data value at the max count.  This will require using a search functions `MAX`, `WHICHN`, `SMALLEST` and counting function `N`.

Example:

The `.T` missing value is used to represent a tie.
*(Tip: There a 26 special missing values, `.A` throught `.Z`)*

```
data have;              input
  ID   Year1   Year2   Year3   Year4   Year5  ;datalines;                                               
   1     19      19      19      19      19   
   2     5       5       9       .       .    
   3     12      45      11      12      12   
   4     14      15      10      14       .   
   5     20      20      19      19      28   
   6     1       2       3       4       4
   7    12      10       1       1       10
   8 . . . . .
   9 . . . 1 .
  10 1 2 3 4 5
  11 2 2 . 3 3
;

data want;
  set have;
  array y year1-year5;
  array v[5];
  array f[5];

  * compute the frequency of each value;
  do over y;
    if missing (y) then continue;
    i = whichn(y, of v(*));
    if i=0 then do;
      n=sum(n,1); 
      i=n;
      v[i] = y;
    end;
    f[i] = sum(f[i],1);
  end;

  if not missing(n) then do;
    * obtain the value index of the max (freq);
    mf = max(of f(*));
    mi = whichn(mf,of f(*));
    mode = v(mi);

    if n > 1 then do;
      mf2 = smallest(n(of f(*))-1, of f(*));
      if mf2 = mf then
        mode = .T;
    end;
  end;
  
  keep id year: mode;

  format _numeric_ 4.;
run;
```

[image]